Deserialize Kotlin Object Based on Enum Property
I'm working on an Android app where I get some data from an API with two properties - one is an enum that describes the data, and the other is the value. The problem I'm having is that the value can be of different types depending on the enum to which it corresponds. The API returns JSON that looks like this:
[ {type: name, value: "bob"}, {type: height, value: 70}, {type: weight, value: 160.25}, {type: metric, value: false} ]
So I have a data object that looks something like:
data class Info(val type: InfoType, val value: (Not sure what to do here))
where InfoType is an enum that looks something like:
enum class InfoType { NAME, HEIGHT, WEIGHT, METRIC }
How can I go about handling this data? Is there a way to set the value data type based on what the InfoType is?

Info shouldn't be a data class.  It should be a sealed interface.
sealed interface Info {
  data class NameInfo(val name: String): Info
  data class HeightInfo(val height: Int): Info
  ...
}

You don't need to keep the type, because the type is held by the subtype you use.  If you need a variable that takes any of them, use Info.  When deserializing, choose what subtype to instantiate based on the value.
